# Adding properties to TopoJSON file using topojson command doesn't load data from external csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to bind some data from a csv to a topojson file but the data from the csv is not being added to the properties of the topojson objects. [Here is the csv file](http://rmoncayo28.github.io/CMPS165/dataSets/education_dataset.csv) and an example of part of it:

```
GEO.id,GEO.id2,GEO.display-label,HC01_EST_VC21,HC01_EST_VC22,HC01_EST_VC23
Id,Id2,Geography,Total; Estimate; Population 18 years and over,Total; Estimate; Population 18 years and over - Enrolled in college or graduate school %,Total; Estimate; Population 18 years and over - Enrolled in college or graduate school #
1400000US06001400100,6001400100,"Census Tract 4001, Alameda County, California",3056,25.5,779
1400000US06001400200,6001400200,"Census Tract 4002, Alameda County, California",1619,4.3,70
```

[Here is the topojson I'm trying to bind the data to](http://rmoncayo28.github.io/CMPS165/dataSets/ca-tracts.json) and an example of part:

```
{"type":"Topology","objects":{"cb_2015_06_tract_500k":{"type":"GeometryCollection","bbox":[-124.409591,32.534155999999996,-114.131211,42.009518],"geometries":[
{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"STATEFP":"06","COUNTYFP":"001","TRACTCE":"400600","AFFGEOID":"1400000US06001400600","GEOID":"06001400600","NAME":"4006","LSAD":"CT","ALAND":297856,"AWATER":0},"arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4]]},
{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"STATEFP":"06","COUNTYFP":"001","TRACTCE":"400900","AFFGEOID":"1400000US06001400900","GEOID":"06001400900","NAME":"4009","LSAD":"CT","ALAND":420877,"AWATER":0},"arcs":[[5,6,7,8]]},
```

I used the command  `topojson -o out.json -e education_dataset.csv --id-property=GEOID,GEO.id2 -p population=+HC01_EST_VC01 -- ca-tracts.json`
to bind `HC01_EST_VC01` from the csv to `population` property in the topojson but the output doesn't have any properties. I also tried the command `topojson -o out.json -e education_dataset.csv --id-property=AFFGEOID,GEO.id -p population=+HC01_EST_VC01 -- ca-tracts.json` as the topojson has both `AFFGEOID` and `GEOID` properties which correspond to columns in the csv `GEO.id` and `GEO.id2`, respectively. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. For --id-property ,may be you cannot use as Ge0.id2, change it into GEO.
2. For --id-property ,in topojson you have GEOID as "06001440335" where your      GEO.id2 is 6001440335.So you should keep + sign infront of them so that it can compare as numbers
   **--id-property=+GEOID,+GEO**
3. HC01_EST_VC01 is not present in given csv file

The working command I made after changing Geo.id2 to GEO and using "HC01_EST_VC21" for population is

**topojson -o out.json -e education_dataset.csv  --id-property=+GEOID,+GEO  -p population=HC01_EST_VC21 -- ca-tracts.json**

feel free to ask any more queries

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work for me. [[This is the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5rvCb1QEBa2bWo0OVpWSHBvWHc/view?usp=sharing) None of the objects have properties. Do you have any more ideas or possibly a different command/method to add the properties? Thanks.

Comment: Did you change your GEO.id2 as GEO in your csv file?

Comment: I copied and pasted the command you provided exactly. Could our topojsons be different? I installed it on ubuntu using npm install -g topojson